# Tokenizing a string in C?

Tags: c, string, parsing, arguments, char

I'm working on a terminal parser for a calculator written in C. 
I cannot figure out how to concatenate all of the numbers that are in between operators to put them into an array.

For example, if the input (command line argument) was "`4+342`", 
it would ideally be `input[] = {"4", "+", "342"}`.

Here's my code so far.  I'm including `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, and `<ctype.h>`.

```
typedef char * string;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  string inputS = argv[1];
  string input[10];
  string temp;
  printf("%s\n", inputS);
  int i;
  int len = strlen(inputS);
  printf("parsed:\n");
  for(i = 0; i < len; inputS++, i++)
  { 
    if(isdigit(*inputS))
    {
      printf("%c",*inputS);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("\n%c\n",*inputS);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

If it is run with `./calc 4+5-546`, it will output:

```
4
+
5
-
546
```

So what's the easiest way to get each line of this into its own array slot?

Comment: !!! There is **no** real string type in C, `char *` is definitely **not** one, and your typedef is **very dangerous** because it will encourage you to do some very wrong things. Pointers don't hold data in C; they point at it, and the memory must be allocated. If you want to call anything `string` in C, be prepared to do a lot of work to build up a half-decent abstraction.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, thanks for explaining that,i'm just starting out with C from Java so I'm just starting to understand how dangerous something like C is, whereas Java runs in a virtual machine and can't mess too much up. Ill keep the char * thing in mind next time. Is there a way you would recommend though? Maybe have a set limit on the char? [50] or so? Or should I just be using malloc to give me the space for it. Sorry if it's a stupid question, like I said, i'm still just a beginner.

Comment: It depends on why you're learning C, tbh. It might very well be that, whatever your reason is for learning C, there's a better way to achieve your goal than by actually learning C. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for size...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef char * string;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string inputS = argv[1];
    string input[50];   /* Up to 50 tokens */
    char   buffer[200];
    int    i;
    int    strnum = 0;
    char  *next = buffer;
    char   c;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s expression\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("input: <<%s>>\n", inputS);
    printf("parsing:\n");

    while ((c = *inputS++) != '\0')
    { 
        input[strnum++] = next;
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            printf("Digit: %c\n", c);
            *next++ = c;
            while (isdigit(*inputS))
            {
                c = *inputS++;
                printf("Digit: %c\n", c);
                *next++ = c;
            }
            *next++ = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Non-digit: %c\n", c);
            *next++ = c;
            *next++ = '\0';
        }
    }

    printf("parsed:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < strnum; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: <<%s>>\n", i, input[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Given the program is called `tokenizer` and the command:

```
tokenizer '(3+2)*564/((3+4)*2)'
```

It gives me the output:

```
input: <<(3+2)*564/((3+4)*2)>>
parsing:
Non-digit: (
Digit: 3
Non-digit: +
Digit: 2
Non-digit: )
Non-digit: *
Digit: 5
Digit: 6
Digit: 4
Non-digit: /
Non-digit: (
Non-digit: (
Digit: 3
Non-digit: +
Digit: 4
Non-digit: )
Non-digit: *
Digit: 2
Non-digit: )
parsed:
0: <<(>>
1: <<3>>
2: <<+>>
3: <<2>>
4: <<)>>
5: <<*>>
6: <<564>>
7: <</>>
8: <<(>>
9: <<(>>
10: <<3>>
11: <<+>>
12: <<4>>
13: <<)>>
14: <<*>>
15: <<2>>
16: <<)>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The *easiest* solution is to use a tool like [flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) to generate your lexer and let it do the work of breaking the input into tokens (although flex expects its input to come from a file stream, not a character array).

`strtok()` isn't a good solution for several reasons:

- It overwrites the input, which you may want to preserve for use later;

  It's a brute force tool and doesn't handle badly-formed input well;

  If you use your arithmetic operators as the token separators, then the operators themselves will get clobbered.

The usual solution is to write a state machine (which is basically what flex does for you).  Here's a *very* quick-n-dirty (emphasis on the dirty) example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/**
 * Read from a string specified by source, updating the pointer as we go.
 * We're assuming that token points to a buffer large enough to hold
 * our largest token; ideally, you would want to pass the length of the
 * target buffer and check against it, but I'm leaving it out for brevity.
 * 
 * Tokens are either integers (strings of digits) or operators. 
 *
 * Return 1 if we successfully read a token, 0 if we encountered an unexpected
 * character, and EOF if the next character is the end of the input string.
 */
int getToken(char **source, char *token)
{
  enum {START, DIGIT, ERROR, DONE} state = START;
  size_t i = 0;
  char *operators="+-*/";

  if (**source == 0)  // at end of input
    return EOF;

  while (**source != 0)
  {
    switch(state)
    {
      /**
       * Initial state for this call.
       */
      case START: 
        if (isdigit(**source))
        {
          state = DIGIT;
          token[i++] = *(*source)++; // append the digit to the token
        }
        else if (strchr(operators, **source) != NULL)
        {
          state = DONE;
          token[i++] = *(*source)++; // add the operator to the token
          token[i++] = 0;            // and terminate the string
        }
        else if (isspace(**source))
        {
          (*source)++;  // ignore whitespace
        }
        else
        {
          /**
           * We've read something that isn't a digit, operator, or 
           * whitespace; treating it as an error for now.
           */
          state = ERR;
        }
        break;

      /**
       * We've read at least one digit.
       */
      case DIGIT:
        if (isdigit(**source))
        {
          token[i++] = *(*source)++; // append next digit to token
        }
        else
        {
          /**
           * We've read a non-digit character; terminate the token
           * and signal that we're done. 
           */
          token[i++] = 0;
          state = DONE;
         }
         break;

      case DONE:
        return 1;
        break;

      case ERR:
        return 0;
        break;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char token[20];
  char *input = argv[1];
  for (;;)
  {
    int result = getToken(&input, token);
    if (result == 1)
      printf("%s\n", token);
    else if (result == 0)
    {
      printf("Bad character '%c'; skipping\n", *input);
      input++;
    }
    else if (result == EOF)
    {
      printf("done\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why `(*source)++` instead of `*source++` or `source++`?  I don't want to update `source`, I want to update what `source` *points to*, so I have to dereference the pointer *before* the `++` is applied.  The expression `*(*source)++` basically translates to "give me the value of the character that the expression `*source` is pointing to, then update the value of `*source`".

Answer (score 1):

--> [MAN STRCAT](http://www.linux-kheops.com/doc/man/manfr/man-html-0.9/man3/strcat.3.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, const char **argv)
{
    char *toto_str = "Toto";
    char *is_str = "Is";
    char *awesome_str = "Awesome";
    char *final_str;
    size_t i;

    i = strlen(toto_str);
    i += strlen(is_str);
    i += strlen(awesome_str);

    final_str = malloc((i * sizeof(char)) + 1);
    strcat(final_str, toto_str);
    strcat(final_str, is_str);
    strcat(final_str, awesome_str);

    printf("%s", final_str);
    free(final_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to ensure that `final_str[0] = '\0';` before launching into your sequence of `strcat()` operations - because `malloc()` does not guarantee to return you initialized (zeroed) data.

Comment: That's how to concatenate, but OP wrote the question badly and isn't actually asking anything about concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

strsep is a good choice here - grab the token and then decide what you want to do with it...

char *string = "(3+(5+6)/8)"

char *token;
while ((token = strsep(&string, "(+/*) "))) {
   // Store token... if it's not a ( or ) or space
}

Here - token will be processed similar to a Split() in Java/C#.  This does mutilate the string while processing it - however, with the correct delimiters - things will be good :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to look at the standard `strtok` function.

Comment: `strtok()` is not helpful here; it tramples NUL '\0' bytes onto the source string at the end of the token, but in the example, there are no spaces that can safely be trampled.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you an idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("\nargv[1]: %s",argv[1]);
    char *p;
    p = strtok(argv[1],"+");
    printf("\np: %s", p);
    p = strtok(NULL,"+");
    printf("\np: %s", p);
    p = strtok(NULL,"+");
    printf("\np: %s", p);
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is just a sample code to demonstrate how it is done using addition case only.
Get the main idea of this code and apply it in your code.
Example output for this:

```
./a.out 5+3+9

argv[1]: 5+3+9
p: 5
p: 3
p: 9
```

Again, I am only demonstrating the "+" sign. You may want to check for p until it is NULL, then proceed with the next operation, say subtraction, then multiplication, then division.

Comment: `strtok()` is not the right tool here; you happen to know that every operator is `+`, but in the question, one of the operators is `-` and if your code is modified to allow for that, `strtok()` obliterates the operators before you get a chance to see what it is.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to why the first argument in most of your strtok's are NULL. I just finished reading about them and I guess I don't fully understand what exactly the function does. Could you explain further why you have to "p = strtok(NULL,"+") until the end of the string?

Comment: @jonathan: you can actualy use it with `4+5-546`. The code will give you `4` and `5-546` allowing you to perhaps parse the `5-546` before adding it to 4 for example.

Comment: @pwnmonkey: pass NULL to iterate through your string. The first strtok points to the string before the "+". Passing it a NULL to strtok will move your pointer to the next string after the "+"

Comment: Suppose the program is to be a 4-function calculator.  How do you decide what the operators are?  They're `"+-*/"`; so you pass that as the second argument to `strtok()`, and it obliterates the operator.  If you have to read ahead to find out what the operator is before you use `strtok()`, then you have defeated the point of using `strtok()`.

Comment: @Jonathan no, he proposes to tokenise the string multiple times - with "+", then with "-" etc. and take notes on what NULLs were inserted on each run.