# How to copy or concatenate two char*

Tags: c++, strcpy, strcat

How do you concatenate or copy char* together?

```
char* totalLine;

const char* line1 = "hello";
const char* line2 = "world";

strcpy(totalLine,line1);
strcat(totalLine,line2);
```

This code produces an error!

```
segmentation fault
```

I would guess that i would need to allocate memory to totalLine?

Another question is that does the following copy memory or copy data?

```
char* totalLine;

const char* line1 = "hello";

 totalLine = line1;
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Just change `char* totalLine` to `char totalLine[12]` (although keep in mind your code is C and not C++)

Comment: You could always stick them in the low and high order bytes of a short ;)

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string`?  It magically solves all problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I would guess that i would need to allocate memory to totalLine?

Yes, you guessed correctly.  `totalLine` is an uninitialized pointer, so those `strcpy` calls are attempting to write to somewhere random in memory.

Luckily, as you've tagged this C++, you don't need to bother with all that.  Simply do this:

```
#include <string>

std::string line1 = "hello";
std::string line2 = "world";

std::string totalLine = line1 + line2;
```

No memory management required.

> does the following copy memory or copy data?

I think you mean "is the underlying string copied, or just the pointer?".  If so, then just the pointer.

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply! i am getting a data from a file and then strtok it, hence i will have it in a char* format. how do i convert it to string? or else how do i solve it?

Comment: `std::string` has a constructor from `char *`, just use that.

Comment: With reference to the link, what if i do not know the size of the text? then how do i convert it to a string?

Comment: @dupdupdup: You don't need to know the size.  `const char *foo = "whatever"; std::string bar = foo;` should work just fine.

Comment: @dupdupdup: You probably should not be using strtok(). You should ask another question on how to achieve the task you are doing in C++ (as you are obviously writting C not C++).

Comment: this answer does not show how to concatenate two char pointers

Comment: @edwardblack: Yes, because that's (usually) insane in C++. This answers the real question, which is "how do I concatenate two strings?".

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you need to allocate memory to `totalLine`.  In C you have a wide range of options of varying levels of awkwardness.   My *preferred* way requires the GNU library extension [`asprintf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) (also available on the BSDs, but not included in POSIX):

```
char *xconcat2(const char *line1, const char *line2) {
    char *totalLine;
    int len = asprintf(&totalLine, "%s%s", line1, line2);
    if (len < 0) abort();
    return totalLine;
}
```

I prefer to do it this way because it's compact, easy to read, and easy to modify.  If you need to stick to strict ISO C, though, in my opinion the next best thing is to write out a series of `strlen` and `memcpy` operations.  I don't like to use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `strcat`, or `strncat` at all, because it's very easy to be [accidentally quadratic](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/) with `strcat` and `strncat`, because it's hard to be sure you don't have a [buffer overflow](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/120.html) bug with them, and because [`strncpy` and `strncat` don't do what you might expect them to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588581/which-functions-in-the-c-standard-library-commonly-encourage-bad-practice).

```
char *xconcat2_iso(const char *line1, const char *line2) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(line1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(line2);

    char *totalLine = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (!totalLine) abort();

    memcpy(totalLine,        line1, len1);
    memcpy(totalLine + len1, line2, len2);
    totalLine[len1 + len2] = '\0';
    return totalLine;
}
```

---

In C++, as recommended in the accepted answer, just use `std::string`.

Comment: Why not `strcpy` and `strcat`?

Comment: @MooingDuck I think calling `strlen` up front, then `memcpy` with the same length variable(s) used in `malloc`, makes it clearer to future readers of my code that there is no possibility of a buffer overflow.  Also, it doesn't matter in this case, but if there were N strings to concatenate, using `strcat` would make the operation O(N²).

Answer (score 1):

`totalLine` has a garbage value

```
const char* Line1{ "Hallo" };  
const char* Line2{ "World" };   
char* TotalLine{ new char[strlen(Line1) + strlen(Line2) + 1] };

TotalLine = strcpy(TotalLine, Line1);
TotalLine = strcat(TotalLine, Line2);
```

> Note=> If you work on Visual Studio you need `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Answer (score 0):

Concentrate "aaa" and "bbb" to "aaabbb":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char* Line1 ="aaa";
    const char* Line2 ="bbb";
    char* TotalLine{ new char[strlen(Line1) + strlen(Line2) + 1] };
    TotalLine = strcpy(TotalLine, Line1);
    TotalLine = strcat(TotalLine, Line2);   
    cout << TotalLine <<endl;
}
```