# exception thrown with sqlite select statement

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am willing to access a particular element present in the coloumn in my SQLite database so in order to achieve this I have used a select statement

```
char *query = {0};
            strcat(query, "SELECT ");//exception thrown here
            strcat(query, (char*)arr);//The value to be asscessed
            strcat(query, " FROM CARS");
```

but this is throwing an exception in ucrtbased.dll why?

**update**

I have referred this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609326/how-to-copy-or-concatenate-two-char) and tried this,`char* line1 = "SELECT ";
                char* line2 = (char*)arr;
                char* line3 = " FROM CARS";
                size_t len1 = strlen(line1);
                size_t len2 = strlen(line2);
                size_t len3 = strlen(line3);
                char *query = (char*)malloc(len1 + len2 + len3 + 1);
                if (!query) abort();
                memcpy(query, line1, len1);
                memcpy(query + len1, line2, len2);
                query[len1 + len2 + len3] = '\0';`

but I found that I've done something wrong(because out put jumps to the else statement which means invalid sqlite statement) which I could not figure it out kindly help me.

I also referred this tutorial  [@ cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) but could not figure it out
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated any memory to `query` and trying to copy some characters into it. You can create a variable on stack like `char query[256] = {0};` if size is known. Else you can allocate memory dynamically using `new[]` and release it using `delete[]`.

Comment: So, I should use malloc? for query variable? Thank you

Comment: @user105127: Updated answer.

Comment: Wouldn't one be better off to use a `std::string` and then spit out a char* with `.c_str()` ? You avoid allocating memory, freeing memory and get simpler concatenation to boot.

Comment: @enhzflep: `c_str()` returns `const char*`. You can not modify the contents of that. If really needed one can use `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @Naveen . I referred from your answer and I referred the internet and tried something but I'm facing errors kindly help me.I have updated my question. Thank you

Comment: @Naveen - yes, I know that. (I was lazy when I omitted the `const` in my last comment - my mistake) It's an sql string - clearly, the purpose of which is to be used to run a query - do you imagine a scenario where one would _want_ to change the string after it was assembled? (I can't) Even if so, wouldn't one just alter the representation held in the `std::string` before emitting another const char* via `.c_str()`? That is to say - I fail to see the benefit of avoiding a `std::string`

Comment: @enhzflep: Yes, you are right (I dont know what I was thinlking :)).. a simple `std::string` is much better here.